# Trouble Understanding With Statement in Nix Expression

Tags: nix

From [Section 12.5 of Nix Pills](https://nixos.org/nixos/nix-pills/inputs-design-pattern.html):

> Finish the expression for graphviz with gd support (**note the use of the with expression in buildInputs to avoid repeating pkgs**):
>
> ```
> let
>   pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
>   mkDerivation = import ./autotools.nix pkgs;
> in mkDerivation {
>   name = "graphviz";
>   src = ./graphviz-2.38.0.tar.gz;
>   buildInputs = with pkgs; [ gd fontconfig libjpeg bzip2 ];
> }
> ```

**Question:** Why is the the `with pkgs` needed at the end of the code snippet in `buildInputs`? I thought `pkgs` was already in scope through the `let` binding at the top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `pkgs` is in scope, but that doesn't automatically put it's attributes into scope.

`pkgs` is a Nix set containing attributes such as `gd`, `fontconfig`... If you drop `with pkgs` then the list of `buildInputs` will not be able to resolve the aforementioned attributes. Using your example, the following two expressions are semantically identical:

```
buildInputs = with pkgs; [ gd fontconfig libjpeg bzip2 ];

buildInputs = [ pkgs.gd pkgs.fontconfig pkgs.libjpeg pkgs.bzip2 ];
```

Here's another example which is also semantically identical:

```
let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
  mkDerivation = import ./autotools.nix pkgs;
  gd = pkgs.gd;
  fontconfig = pkgs.fontconfig;
  libjpeg = pkgs.libjpeg;
  bzip2 = pkgs.bzip2;
in mkDerivation {
  name = "graphviz";
  src = ./graphviz-2.38.0.tar.gz;
  buildInputs = [ gd fontconfig libjpeg bzip2 ];
}
```

In the last example, `gd`, `fontconfig`... are brought into scope in the first part of the `let` expression, and then used in `buildInputs` without the `with pkgs`.

Hopefully that will help you intuit what `with pkgs` is doing.